# How many quadratic residues of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ are in the kernel of a morphism $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}^+\to \mathbb{F}_p^+$?

Tags: finite-fields, quadratic-residues

Given an odd prime $p$ and a positive integer $n$, let $QR$ be the set of non-zero quadratic residues in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. Suppose we have a non-trivial (additive) group homomorphism $f\colon \mathbb{F}_{p^n}^+\to \mathbb{F}_p^+$, where $\mathbb{F}_q^+$ denotes the additive group of the field $\mathbb{F}_q$. Then what can we say about the cardinality of $QR\cap \operatorname{ker}(f)$?

Very limited calculations suggest the answer is always $(p^{n-1}-1)/2$ when $n$ is odd. But things appear to change when $n$ is even. For $p=5$ and $n=2$, the cardinality can be either $0$ or $4$, for example.  The odd case seems consistent with this vague understanding I have of the quadratic residues being semi-randomly distributed through half of the field (so of the $p^{n-1}-1$ non-zero elements of the kernel, then it seems reasonable to suspect that half of them would be residues); but I'm not sure how to formally establish this, or see how $n$ being even changes things.

Comment: If $n$ is a QR by and odd prime then it is a QR for $p^n$ for all $n$. However ths is not true for $2$. But if you are a QR modulo $8$, then you are a QR modulo all powers of $2$. So maybe change the image in your question to the field with $8$ elements, then you may get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I'm not interested in the characteristic 2 case, though if an answer handles that as well then all the nicer (though this should be trivial; isn't everything a quadratic residue in char 2?). Also, "modulo 8" and "the field with 8 elements" are not the same thing.

Comment: I dont get it. Your fields have characteristic $p$.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Well, yes, of course.  What of it? How do you suddenly start talking about the field with 8 elements when I'm explicitly working in odd characteristic, and therefore odd order additive groups?

Comment: Oh sorry you have $n=2$, I thought it was p. Ok so my comments are beside the point.

Comment: What does $\mathbb{F}_p^+$ mean? I have never seen the $+$ notation before in this context.

Comment: @carmichael561 It means the additive group of the field.  Added this to the post.

Comment: All such additive homomorphisms are gotten from the recipe $f(x)=tr(zx)$, where $z$ is a (fixed) element of $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$, and $tr$ is the trace mapping $$tr:\Bbb{F}_{p^n}\to\Bbb{F}_p, x\mapsto x+x^p+x^{p^2}+\cdots+x^{p^{n-1}}.$$ Looks like character sums will have a lot to say about your question. I need to wrap my head around this (too late an hour at the moment).

Comment: We certainly get a non-trivial bound on the number of squares in the kernel by applying standard estimates to character sums
$$\sum_{a=0}^{p-1}\sum_{x\in \Bbb{F}_{p^n}}e(azx^2).$$ Here $z$ is the element related to $f$ (see the previous comment), and $e(x)=e^{2\pi i tr(x)/p}$ is the canonical additive character.

Comment: The contributions coming from different non-zero $a$ in the above sum are Galois conjugates of each other, and that may (?) help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an entertaining soup of basic facts about character sums over finite fields. But let me first record the following fact from the comments:

**Fact 1.** To each element $z\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ we get a homomorphism $f_z$ from the additive group of $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ to the additive group of the prime field $\Bbb{F}_p$ from the recipe
$$f_z(x)=tr(zx),$$
where $tr$ is the trace map defined by
$$tr(x)=x+x^p+x^{p^2}+\cdots+x^{p^{n-1}}=\sum_{\sigma\in Gal(\Bbb{F}_{p^n}/\Bbb{F}_p)}\sigma(x).$$
Furthermore, distinct choices of $z$ yield different homomorphisms, and all the homomorphisms between these groups are of this form.

**Proof.** This is textbook stuff. The bigger additive group is an $n$-dimensional vector space over the prime field. Hence the homomorphisms are exactly the elements of the dual space, and there are exactly $p^n$ of them.
The mapping $f_z$ is a homomorphism of additive groups because it is the sum of such beasts. If $z\neq0$ then the kernel of $f_z$ cannot have more than $p^{n-1}$ elements, because it is given by a polynomial of degree $p^{n-1}$. As $f_z-f_{z'}=f_{z-z'}$ we get as a corollary that $f_z\neq f_{z'}$ whenever $z\neq z'$. Therefore we have listed all the $p^n$ homomorphisms. **QED.**

I also need to list the following leading actors:

- The canonical additive character $e:\Bbb{F}_{p^n}^+\to\Bbb{C}^*$
  $$e(x)=e^{2\pi i tr(x)/p}.$$
- The unique quadratic multiplicative character of order two (= the
  Legendre character) $\eta:\Bbb{F}_{p^n}\to\{0,\pm1\}$: $$
     \eta(x)=\begin{cases} 0,&\ \text{if $x=0$,}\\
     +1,&\ \text{if $x$ is a non-zero square,} \\-1,&\ \text{if $x$ is a non-square.}\end{cases} $$
- The basic geometric sum:
  $$\sum_{a=0}^{p-1}e(ax)=\begin{cases}p,\ \text{if $tr(x)=0$,}\\0,\ \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
- The [Gauss' sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum)
  $$G(p^n)=\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}}e(x)\eta(x).$$

The value of the Gauss' sum is well-known (search for Gauss' sign problem and [Hasse-Davenport relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%E2%80%93Davenport_relation)):
$$
\begin{aligned}
G(p)&=\begin{cases}\sqrt p,&\ \text{if $p\equiv1\pmod4$},\\ 
i\sqrt p,&\ \text{if $p\equiv-1\pmod4$.}\end{cases}\\
G(p^n)&=-(-G(p))^n.
\end{aligned}
$$

**Fact 2.** Let $f_z:\Bbb{F}_{p^n}^+\to\Bbb{F}_p^+$ be the above homomorphism, $z\neq0$.
Let $N(z)$ be the number of non-zero squares in the kernel of $f_z$. Then
$$2p N(z)=\sum_{a=0}^{p-1}\sum_{y\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}, y\neq0}e(azy)(1+\eta(y)).$$

**Proof.** Here $1+\eta(y)=2$ when $y$ a non-zero square, and $1+\eta(y)=0$ otherwise, so this follows from the basic geometric sum. **QED.**

Next I will concentrate on evaluating that character sum. Let's first fix a value for $a$, and let's include $y=0$ into the summation (so that we can apply the orthogonality of characters).

- If $a=0$, then $\sum_{y\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}}e(azy)(1+\eta(y))=p^n$, because we can ignore the factor $e(azy)=1$, and $\eta$ takes both values $\pm1$ equally often, i.e. $(p^n-1)/2$ times.
- OTOH if $a\neq0$ then
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  \sum_{y\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}}e(azy)(1+\eta(y))&=
  \sum_{y\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}}e(azy)+\sum_{y\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}}e(azy)\eta(y)\\
  &=\sum_{y\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}}e(azy)\eta(y),\qquad\text{by orthogonality of characters the other sum vanishes}\\
  &=\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}}e(x)\eta(x/(az)),\qquad\text{by the change of variable $x=ayz$}\\
  &=\eta(1/(az))\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}}e(x)\eta(x),\qquad\text{by multiplicativity of $\eta$}\\
  &=\eta(a)\eta(z) G(p^n).
  \end{aligned}
  $$

Let me record that in a sum $\sum_{y\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}}e(azy)(1+\eta(y))$ the contribution of $y=0$ is always equal to $+1$. Using all of the above in Fact 2, we get the following result:

> $2pN(z)=p^n+\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\eta(a)\eta(z) G(p^n)\quad -p.$

With the aid of this formula we can explain some of your observations:

- If $n$ is odd, then exactly one half of the non-zero elements $a$ of the prime field, namely the quadratic residues modulo $p$, are squares in $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$. This is because the rest of them are squares of elements of $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$, but those are now excluded. Therefore $\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\eta(a)=0$, and
  $$
  N(z)=\frac{p^n-p}{2p}=\frac12(p^{n-1}-1).
  $$
- But if $n$ is even, then $\eta(a)=+1$ for all $a=1,2,\ldots,p-1$. In this case we get
  $$
  N(z)=\frac{p^n+(p-1)\eta(z)G(p^n)-p}{2p}.
  $$
  The extra term with the Gauss' sum has absolute value $(p-1)p^{n/2}$. Its sign depends on the choice of $z$, i.e. on the choice of the homomorphism. In your example case of $p=5,n=2$ we get, all in line with your experimental data,
  $$
  N(z)=\frac{25\pm4\cdot5-5}{2\cdot5}=4\ \text{or}\ 0.
  $$

Comment: I initially suspected that we might get other Gauss sums as well. Wonder why? Anyway, we won't be needing my earlier hunch that Gauss sums being Galois conjugates would be helpful. This "plain" Gauss sum can be calculated explicitly, and it is a rational integer.

Comment: I'm having second thoughts. Do we really need character sums here? At the moment I don't see how to get around the use of Gauss' sums, but may be there is a way. Obviously the answer only depends on whether $z$ is a square or a non-square. This is because precomposing a given homomorphism with multiplication by a square won't change the number of squares in the kernel! Thinking....

Comment: Well, I don't think it's particularly elegant, but I was just recently thinking maybe we could use that $tr(x)=0$ if and only if $x=y^p-y=y(y^{p-1}-1)$ for some $y\in\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ and then doing a case-by-case check for when $\eta(y)=\eta(y^{p-1}-1)$.  I assume that dodges the sums, but I haven't even checked if it actually works out in a clean manner, so...

Answer (score 1):

Listing what I can do without character sums. Hopefully this can also be completed later. At the moment it is anything but a full solution.

Again, let $f_z:\Bbb{F}_{p^n}\to\Bbb{F}_p$ be the homomorphism $f_z(x)=tr(zx)$,
and let $N(z)$ be the number of non-zero squares in the kernel of $f_z$.

A key observation is that a non-zero square $y^2\in \operatorname{ker}(f_z)$
if and only if the non-zero square $(cy)^2\in\operatorname{ker}(f_{z/c^2})$. This implies immediately that for all $z,c\in \Bbb{F}_{p^n}^*$ we have
$$
N(z)=N(z/c^2).
$$
So if $g$ is a primitive element, i.e. a generator of the multiplicative group $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}^*$, then $N(z)=N(1)$ whenever $z$ is a square, and $N(z)=N(g)$ whenever $z$ is a non-square.

On the other hand each and every non-zero element of $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ is, by basic linear algebra, in the kernel of exactly $p^{n-1}$ distinct homomorphisms (including the zero homomorphism) from $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}\to\Bbb{F}_p$. Therefore, counting the number of pairs $(z,x)$ where $x$ is a non-zero square in the kernel of $f_z$ in the two obvious ways, gives
$$
p^{n-1}\left(\frac{p^n-1}2\right)=\left(\frac{p^n-1}2\right)\left(N(1)+N(g)+1\right).
$$
In other words, we have the equation
$$
N(1)+N(g)=p^{n-1}-1.
$$

This means that if we can determine the number $N(1)$, then we have completely solved the main problem.

Unfortunately I don't know how to calculate $N(1)$ without character sums. Except in the case $n=2$. Let me share.

An element $x\in\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ is in the kernel of $f_1$ if and only if
$$
0=tr(x)=x^p+x.
$$
Assuming, as we do, that $x\neq0$ this is equivalent to  the equation 
$$x^{p-1}=-1.\qquad(*)$$ Because $g$ was a generator (of order $p^2-1$), we can write $x=g^t$. It is well known that $g^{(p^2-1)/2}=-1$. Therefore $(*)$ is equivalent to
$$
g^{(p^2-1)/2}=-1=x^{p-1}=g^{t(p-1)},
$$
which is, in turn, equivalent to the congruence
$$
t(p-1)\equiv \frac{p^2-1}2\pmod {p^2-1}.
$$
Cancelling the obvious factor $p-1$ leaves us with the congruence
$$
t\equiv\frac{(p+1)}2\pmod {p+1}.\qquad(**)
$$
Because $p+1$ is even, the solutions of $(**)$ are either all even or all odd
according to the parity of $(p+1)/2$. Therefore, when $n=2$, the non-zero elements in the kernel of $f_1$ are either all squares or all non-squares. The former case occurs when $p\equiv-1\pmod4$ and the latter when $p\equiv1\pmod4$.

> Summary #1: When $n=2$ we have the simple result that $N(1)=p-1, N(g)=0$, if $p\equiv-1\pmod4$. If $p\equiv1\pmod 4$, then the reverse holds, and $N(1)=0, N(g)=p-1$.

---

What about the case of $n>2$? The kernel of $f_z$ is always a subspace over the prime field. We can thus partition the non-zero elements of the kernel into 1-dimensional subspaces, rays if you wish, over the prime field. If $n$ is an odd number, then
(see also my other answer) exactly one half of the non-zero elements of the prime field are squares in the field $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$. Therefore, along each and every one of those rays, exactly one half of the elements are squares, and the other half are non-squares. This explains Zibadawa Timmy's observation:

> Summary #2: When $2\nmid n$ we have $N(1)=N(g)=(p^{n-1}-1)/2$.

What's missing is a simple counting argument for $N(1)$ when $2\mid n$, $n\ge4$. Calling it a day.

Comment: I like this proof the most since it's a clear, simple argument for the cases I was most interested in.  I've accepted your other one because it covers all cases.